# angular-cli update service-worker id of undefined error

Tags: angular, angular-cli, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've followed the official guide of angular and successfully installed the initial service worker. Next I wanted to tryout the updating behaviour and got a

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

where as id refers to client.id in a method in ngsw-worker.js

```
async updateClient(client) {
        // Figure out which version the client is on. If it's not on the latest,
        // it needs to be moved.
        const existing = this.clientVersionMap.get(client.id);
....
}
```

The steps i did are

1. Register SW, went offline and reloaded (worked), closed tab but kept window open
2. Updated code in app.cmp.html
3. Rebuilt project (ng build --prod)
4. opened new Tab and the app (could observe SW update)
5. reload app
6. error

I'm using angular-cli 1.7.4 and all angular libraries including service-worker are on 5.2.10.

**Edit 1** 08.05.2018

There is an issue posted on github on angular-cli 6 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23742

**Edit 2** 08.05.2018

What I could find out so far:

ng build --prod does not create a new version of ngsw-worker.js (on reloading the new fresh build, chrome does not display the "wait for activation"). When I reload with or without closing the tab prior, the error appears.

When I manually add something to ngsw-worker.js (like a console.log) then the usually lifecycle starts and the old service worker is being replace by the "new" one.

When I reload before the activation is being done, the same error appears. Otherwise it works...

Furthermore trying to remove the service-worker using angular's Fail-safe (removing or renaming the ngsw-config) causes a build error.

> Expected to find an ngsw-config.json configuration file in the /Users/hanche/Desktop/Development/playground/toggl2 folder. Either provide one or disable Service Worker in your angular.json configuration file.

**Edit 3 & 'Solution'** 09.05.2018

This issues is supposed to get fixed if this [Pull Request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/23625) from 1st May 2018 is accepted.

Meanwhile, you can auto-unregister the serviceworker by removing the ngsw.json from the dist/ folder and NOT ngsw-config.json as described in the fail safe section. See [reply I got here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23767#issuecomment-387690966).

Furthermore it could also be a [chrome bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23526)

Comment: Regardless of programming language used, have you tried debugging if 'client' object is a valid object?

Comment: @noogui - how is that supposed to done. Any reference of code here? I need this help as well.

Comment: Did you find how to fix this issue??

Answer (score 2):

In our case the problem was resolved after upgrading to angular 6.0.0. If it's possible for your project, you should give that a try.

I looked at the ngsw-worker.js and it changed quite a bit in 6.0.0 compared to (in our case) 5.2.0.

Comment: Hi csim, did you experience the same id of undefined error before with updating you prod builds?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you're asking if we had the same error then yes.

Answer (score 1):

We can work around this error by downgrading service.worker 5.2.10 to 5.2.0 `"@angular/service-worker": "5.2.0",`

**Update**

After a second deploy we ran into the same error. Now we have unregistered all service workers in chrome (chrome://serviceworker-internals/) and now it seems to work with version 5.2.10 also. Don't know where the problem lies.

Comment: will try this out, thanks. The big issue of course is on who to deal with the apps that are already out there in production...

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Maybe it can be good to unregister service workers programmatically?

Comment: The main issue is how to remove them from already "infected" devices from your "customers", who have used your app. But see my edit 3 for that.

Comment: unregistering service workers from chrome://serviceworker-internals/ worked to fix the problem